# Chrome 44 no longer supports the following syntax: window.location.href = "javascript:someFunction()"

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

With the update of Chrome from 43 to 44, the following syntax no longer works:

```
window.location.href = "javascript:alert()"
```

I'm trying to load the contents of a page from local storage.  I'm doing this by returning the page contents as the result of a javascript function call.  I need to specify a URL as the target for window.  Rather than specifying `http://....`, I used to be able to specify `javascript` as the scheme in the URL and specify the name of the function to invoke.

Apparently, Google took this feature away in version 44.  Has anyone run into this and figured out an alternative?

Comment: Still working in Chrome 44.0.2403.107 (64-bit) on OS X

Comment: Still working in Chrome 44.0.2403.107 on Windows 8.1

Comment: Still working in 44.0.2403.107 m (64-bit) in Windows 7

Comment: A fallback alternative you could use is `window.document.clear(); window.document.write( your_function() )`.

Comment: [Mark](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5165854/mark) posted this - *"I did a report issue on 7/26/2015 to Google on Chrome 44/45 with this issue of the JavaScript protocol used to load the page. I included example code in the report. The page does load for me BUT nothing is shown (using debugger the elements are there but not rendered and are in top left corner). Seems like a css/style bug in Chrome."* (it was originally an answer)

Comment: Maybe a chicken&egg problem if the function was defined by the old page? But have you tried a data url instead, i.e.: location.href= 'data:text/html;base64,'+btoa('<script>alert("hiya")</script>')

Comment: Still working in Chrome 44.0 (Mac OS X 10.10.2)

Answer (score 1):

For others finding this page, it's an official [bug now](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=518925)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is working for page itself, but not working for an iframe. This used to work in versions prior to *Chrome 44*. Even in *Chrome 44*, document is built and all events are fired, but the page won't be visible in iframe. The frame will start showing the contents if style attribute position for iframe is removed and added again. Here is the sample code illustrating workaround for *Chrome 44*.

**chrome44.html**

```
<html>
    <script>
        function getFrame(theFrameID)
        {
            return document.getElementById(theFrameID);
        }
        function loadFrameSource()
        {
            var aFrame = getFrame("frm");
            aFrame.src = "chrome44frame.html";
            // had to add the following line as a workaround for Chrome 44
            aFrame.style.position = "absolute";
        }
    </script>
    <body onload="loadFrameSource()">
        <iframe id="frm" style="position : absolute;">
    </body>
</html>
```

**chrome44frame.html**

```
<html>
    <script>
        function getHtml()
        {
            // Hard coding frame content for illustrating here, but actual script does more
            return "<html> <body onload=\"document.getElementById('evnt').innerText='onload event fired.';\">href  is Successful in changing html. <div id='evnt'>, but onload event didn't fire.</div></body> </html>";
        }
        function  loadPage()
        {
            document.location.href="javascript:getHtml('href')";
            // Had to add the following line as a workaround for Chrome 44
            window.parent.getFrame("frm").style.position = "";
        }
        loadPage();
    </script>
</html>
```